# Missing Universal Windows Platform template with Build vNext

Tags: uwp, tfs-2015

i want to create a CI Build for a Windows Universal Platform app.

According to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/apps/universal) should you create a new build and select the appropriate template.

I have this UWP template not for selection.
Only Visual Studio, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and Xcode are available as templates to choose from.
I use the TFS 2015 with Update 1 on-premise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UWP build option is listed in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services, formerly VSO (Visual Studio Online) which is Microsoft hosted TFS service).

[image]

I suspect you are running TFS 2015 on premises.  I don't see this build option on the TFS feature timeline but in general features in VSTS will be available in the next TFS update.  I believe TFS 2015 Update 2 will arrive before April.

Answer (score 0):

The UWP template is only available for VSO for now. However the template is just a combination of several tasks and settings. You can create a build definition on your TFS project and refer to VSO UWP template to add tasks and settings.

Since TFS 2015 support Rest API, if you want to have this template on TFS. you can get the configuration of UWP template from VSO project and create a UWP build template in your TFS base on the infromation you get from VSO via Rest API: [Build definition templates](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/build/definition-templates)